# SQL: Populate single row(tbl 1) from multiple rows(tbl 2); cross DB

Tags: sql, t-sql, insert, case-when

I have created a single table in my primary DB called `tblGlobalIDMapping` that will assign a GUID to all entries and store the other 3 primary ID's across the App to provide for a single ID repository.

The new Table is in the following structure -->

```
AppGlobalID     uniqueidentifier     NoNulls
PersonID        int                  NoNulls
DRIMaster       int                  Nulls
DRIClient       int                  Nulls
```

The information I need is in a table in a different DB (same server) with the following partial structure -->

```
PersonID                int             NoNulls
ApplicationID           tinyint         NoNulls
PersonApplicationID     varchar(14)     NoNulls
```

A person(ID# 13579) is represented in the second table 1 for each Application.  The ApplicationID column stores a number, 1 for DRIMaster and 6 for DRIClient, that tells you what the ID# in PersonApplicationID is for.

I need to do a Bulk Copy/Insert from that table to my new table but I want only 1 row recording the 3 main ID's in the new table.

This is what I have so far but this returns a row for each PersonID.

```
SELECT PersonID, 
    CASE
        WHEN ApplicationID = 1
        THEN PersonApplicationID
    END AS 'DRIMaster', 
    CASE
        WHEN ApplicationID = 6
        THEN PersonApplicationID
    END AS 'DRIClient'
FROM tblApplicationAssociation
WHERE ApplicationID IN (1,6)
```

This returns the below -->

```
PersonID  DRIMaster   DRIClient
_______________________________
108574    71163       NULL
108574    NULL        71163
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregates ignore nulls, so....

```
SELECT PersonID, 
       Min(CASE
                WHEN ApplicationID = 1
                THEN PersonApplicationID
        END) AS 'DRIMaster', 
       Min(CASE
                WHEN ApplicationID = 6
                THEN PersonApplicationID
        END) AS 'DRIClient'
FROM tblApplicationAssociation
WHERE ApplicationID IN (1,6)
Group By PersonId
```

Comment: This seems to work.  I am a little concerned that a DISTINCT PersonID query returns 51241 and this query returns 51233 and I can't currently explain the missing 8 PersonID's.

Comment: You are filtering on ApplicationId In (1,6).  Is is possible that the 8 missing people don't have those two application id's?

Comment: That was my original thought but the following query --> `SELECT DISTINCT PersonID
FROM tblApplicationAssociation
WHERE ApplicationID NOT IN (1,6)` Returns 13253 records....I am stumped!

Comment: I got it, The above query is idiotic on my part and drastically over simplified.  The following query returns the 8 culprits --> `SELECT DISTINCT PersonID
FROM tblApplicationAssociation
WHERE PersonID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT PersonID
FROM tblApplicationAssociation
WHERE ApplicationID IN (1,6))`